# How do I find out what's taking up most of the space on my SQL CLOUD GCP?

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I could not identify what is taking up most of my SQL Cloud Storage, in the last 24 hours something wrote almost 1 Gigabit on the storage, according to the GCP dashboards.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNa3S.png)

If I use MySQL client to determine the size of my tables, the values didn't match with my storage use.

`+--------------------+-----------+
| Database           | Size (MB) |
+--------------------+-----------+
| information_schema |      0.01 |
| mysql              |      6.92 |
| performance_schema |      0.00 |
| XXX_db2014         |    480.25 |
| XXX_db2015         |    282.86 |
| XXX_db2017         |    208.14 |
| XXX_db2018         |    215.44 |
+--------------------+-----------+`

Any idea on how to determine what is taking up most of the space?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You might be incurring storage overhead due to binary logging. In order to see the size of binary logs, run the MySQL command `SHOW BINARY LOGS`.

Per [this GCP documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/instance-info#available_metrics), "Binary logs use storage space. Binary logs are automatically deleted with their associated automatic backup, which generally happens after about 7 days. You cannot manually delete binary logs, nor change the 7-day time period."

Additional reference - [Cloud SQL Binary logging impact](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/replication/tips#bin-log-impact)

Comment: Hi @Daniel, The Binary logging is disabled in my instance.
mysql> SHOW BINARY LOGS;
ERROR 1381 (HY000): You are not using binary logging

Comment: Do you have automatic backup enabled then? Just curious if backup might be contributing to the storage size - https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/backup-recovery/backups